# web.php seems to be okay but BindingResolutionException Target class does not exist. I am looking for a way to remove extra junk rubbish path

Tags: laravel

I use Laravel 6.2

web.php seems to be okay however, BindingResolutionException Target class  [App\Http\Controllers\App\Stack\Http\Controllers\HomeController] does not exist.

I think "App\Http\Controllers" is reductant .
How should I remove this extra junk path?

error happens.

Where should fix it?

web.php

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('/home');
});


Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Stack\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Stack\Http\Middleware\SetDefaultLayoutForUrls;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth', SetDefaultLayoutForUrls::class]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('home');
    }
```

the file is located at
{thisProject}/app/Http/Controllers

Answer (score -1):

In web.php you say that the controller is at :

```
App\Stack\Http\Controllers\HomeController
```

but in your comment you say that the controller is at

```
{thisProject}/app/Http/Controllers
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your homecontroller namespace to:

`namespace App\Stack\Http\Controllers;`

And your route to:

`Route::get('/home', 'App\Stack\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index')->name('home');`

Comment: Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController] does not exist.
occurs.
Nothing is changed.

Comment: I really want to remove this extra junk  rubbish path.

Comment: Your route is searching your controller on App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\HomeController path but it should be on App\Http\Controllers
can you show be the web.php content please.
Theres something wrong with your namespace defined either in controller class or web.php